# Why email on one address was received but not on another address

Tags: amazon-web-services, mx-record

I recently moved my website from `xyz hosting` company to `AWS`, I also made few changes in `NS` records. and created an email address (that was previously there but previous developer some how manged to delete or some thing not sure).

for `mail.mysite.com`, I was pointing to **old** server's ip address. I was still able to receive emails on another address `support@mysite.com` but not on new email address `sales@mysite.com`.

Then I made a `MX record lookup`, it returned **nothing**... strange but at the same time I was reciving emails on support@ address.

Some how I manged to find history of MX record, and made same **MX** entry on `AWS` Route 53. Now I am able to recive emails on new address as well.

> My Questions is why I was receiving emails on one address but not on
>   another address?

Comment: Did you get any bounce back messages while trying to send email to sales@mysite.com ?

Comment: That should not be possible, at least for any extended period. Perhaps it has something to do with caching of the old MX record by one more more MTAs. You haven't said which server was receiving email at which point, the old ISP or the new AWS server. I assume that if no MX record is present the A record is used, so I'd expect email to go to the new server once the DNS has "propogated" (actually, caches cleared). The mail.mysite.com DNS entry is likely irrelevant for email addresses @mysite.com IMHO.

Comment: @Tim I am not exactly sure but your answer for caching seems to be pretty satisfying in a sense, "Needed some logic to hold on to". If you want to add your comment as answer sure I can accept that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should not be possible, at least for any extended period. Perhaps it has something to do with caching of the old MX record by one more more MTAs. You haven't said which server was receiving email at which point, the old ISP or the new AWS server. I assume that if no MX record is present the A record is used, so I'd expect email to go to the new server once the DNS has "propagated" (actually, caches cleared). The mail.mysite.com DNS entry is likely irrelevant for email addresses @mysite.com IMHO.